# ANTLR4 - How do I get know where in the input program ANTLR cannot make deterministic desision

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr4

I have written a grammar in ANTLR 4 and I wanted to parsed it for testing input program, but it threw an ViableException during parsing. Now, I wonder, if the grammar is non-deterministic or only bad written for ANTLR 4 and I want to know, how to fix it? Is there any helpful tool for optimizing and validating LL(*) grammars? I have found only some default tools which did not discovered some error, or did not validated it correctly. ANTLR throws error at line 1 with part of line 2 for 2 standalone commands, and I do not know if the error is exactly here or it can be anywhere deeper in the program.

Error Message which was caught at line 1 by my SyntaxError listenner base on ANTLR BaseErrorListenner:

> 2015-05-02 14:31:45 [ERROR]   [Templates\Java\DocBook\Plan Examples\One Document.PeKLXT]: Exception (Utils.ParsingException) was thrown... Message: Parsing failed... First Error at: no viable alternative at input '@@import: "XDoc_Generator.dll";\t//XDocProject dll\n\n\n\n@@registerVar: XDoc_Generator.XDocProject '   errors: 1
>   Caused by:    v PeKLXT.NET.Engine.parse(String inputProgramFile) v c:\Users\petrk_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Argutec_XDoc\PeKLXT.NET\Engine.cs:řádek 51

As you can see, ANTLR has written to the error message only first rule and the part of the second rule, so is here in this context an error or it can be somewhere deeper in this program?

```
'@@import: "XDoc_Generator.dll";\t//XDocProject dll
\n\n\n\n@@registerVar: XDoc_Generator.XDocProject '
```

The whole code for these 2 rules:

```
@@import: "XDoc_Generator.dll"; //XDocProject dll



@@registerVar: XDoc_Generator.XDocProject #project = (XDocProject)(#this);
```

And here is the grammar for these rules, I have checked it for determinism, also by some internet tool, but I have not found a mismatch:
**PeKLXT.g4:**

```
compileUnit
: (LINECOMMENT | MULTILINECOMMENT)* importCommand*(registerGlobalVariableCommand LINECOMMENT?)* outerBodyCommand* EOF #PeKLXTProgram
| (LINECOMMENT | MULTILINECOMMENT)* importCommand* (MULTILINECOMMENT)? functionDeclaration)+ EOF #FunctionCodeFile
;
```

Function:

```
functionDeclaration
: '@@function' ':' InnerIdentifier '(' parameters? ')' innerBody ';'?
;
```

OuterBody Command: Each command starts with different key word!

```
outerBodyCommand 
: createCommand
| outerOpenCommand   
| outerIfCommand
| outerLoopCommand
| setVariableCommand
;
```

Other used commands and expressions for this context:

```
importCommand
: '@@import' ':' stringExpression ';' LINECOMMENT?
;

registerGlobalVariableCommand 
: '@@registerVar' ':' type emptyArrayDimensions? identifier ('=' assignmentExpression)? ';' //local variable starts with ##
| '@@registerVar' ':' '$xdocument' '='  stringExpression ';'
| '@@registerVar' ':' stat='$$$static' '='  dolarVariableExpression ';'
;
emptyArrayDimensions
: emptyIndexerUnit+ 
;
emptyIndexerUnit
: '[' (',')* ']'
;
assignmentExpression
: conditionExpression
;
```

String expressions:

```
stringExpression
:  stringForm (AdditiveOp stringForm)*
;
stringForm
: unaryExpression
;
stringMethod
: StringMethodName '(' parameterValues? ')'
;
```

Unary Expression (the expressions unit it equals to condition expression in case of no operators between two or more expressions):

```
unaryExpression
: strictlyUnaryExpression
| op='+'   strictlyUnaryExpression 
| op='-'   strictlyUnaryExpression 
| op='!'   strictlyUnaryExpression   
| '('   unaryExpression   ')'
;
strictlyUnaryExpression
: literal('->' stringMethod)*
| objectCall('->' stringMethod)*
| castExpression ('->' stringMethod)*
| dolarVariableExpression ('->' stringMethod)*
;

literal
: StringLiteral
| IntegerLiteral
| DecimalFloatingPointLiteral
| BooleanLiteral
| NullLiteral
;
StringLiteral
:   '"' StringCharacters? '"'
;
fragment
StringCharacters
:   StringCharacter+
;
fragment
StringCharacter
:   ~["\\]
|   EscapeSequence
;
```

Dollar Variable Expression:

```
dolarVariableExpression
: dolarVariableContext
| '$$$tmp' ':' innerSelect
;
innerSelect
: '@@innerSelect' ':' (first='first'|last='last')? '(' innerSelect ')' ('where' '(' conditionExpression ')')?
| '@@innerSelect' ':' (first='first'|last='last')? '(' localDolarIdentifier ':' dolarVariableContext ')' ('where' '(' conditionExpression ')')?
;
```

Types and identifiers:

```
//types

type
: PrimitiveType
| typeIdentifier generics?
;

//string [,,] neco = new string [2, 2,4] {{{"5", "5", "5", "5"}, {"5", "5", "5", "5"}}, {{"5", "5", "5", "5"}, {"5", "5", "5", "5"}}};
emptyArrayDimensions
: emptyIndexerUnit+ 
;

generics
: '<' type (',' type)* '>'
;

//identifiers

//complexIdentifier
//: identifier ('.' InnerIdentifier)*
//;

identifier
: '#' InnerIdentifier   #IdentifierGlobal
| localIdentifier       #IdentifierLocal
| '###' InnerIdentifier #IdentifierStatic
;

localIdentifier
: '##' InnerIdentifier
;

typeIdentifier
: InnerIdentifier ('.' InnerIdentifier)*
;

dolarVariableContext
: dolarPartCall ('.' dolarPartCall)* (InnerIdentifier)?
//| '$$' Pointer ('.' dolarPartCall)* (InnerIdentifier)?
| localDolarIdentifier (indexerGet)? ('.' dolarPartCall)* (InnerIdentifier)?
;

localDolarIdentifier
: '$$' InnerIdentifier
;

dolarPartCall
: '$' InnerIdentifier (indexerGet)?
| '$' Pointer (indexerGet)?
;
fragment InnerIdentifier
: IdentifierStart IdentifierPart*
;
IdentifierStart : [_a-zA-Z]+;
IdentifierPart : [_a-zA-Z0-9]+;
```

Characters to skip:

```
WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
;

MULTILINECOMMENT
    : '/*' .*? '*/'
    ;

LINECOMMENT
    : '//' ~[\r\n]*
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '<!--' (.)*? '-->' -> skip
    ;
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: It seems to me, that import does not expect an ':' (colon). If this is not the problem, then provide the rule for `Identifier`.

Comment: Yes, there was a problem, too... also @ was missing for registerGloablVar Command, but I fixed it and it throws exactly the same error!!!

Comment: Identifier is classic Java Lexer Identifier...

Comment: Your error message is `no viable alternative at input '@@import: "XDoc_Generator.dll";\t//XDocProject dll\n\n\n\n@@registerVar: XDoc_Generator.XDocProject '`. That means that it does matches the prefix of this snippet, but it fails at the complete snippet. Usually this is caused by lexer disambiguities. Now the exact diagnosis cannot be done because the grammar is incomplete (e.g. PrimitiveType misses). Provide a your complete working grammar (or a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) so that anyone could reproduce this behavior.